# I need this to work without the library functions. Is there a way to reverse engineer what the function is doing?

Tags: c++11

```
//checks if ip address is valid format

bool is_ip(char * ip)
{

    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
    int con = sscanf_s(ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    if (4 == con)
    {
        if ((0 <= a && a <= 255) && (0 <= b && b <= 255) && (0 <= c && c <= 255) && (0 <= d && d <= 255))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Are you trying to reverse engineer `sscanf_s`? You don't need to -- it's a documented function.

Comment: The [behaviour is defined by the standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) It's reading 4 numbers separated by `.`s

Comment: It parses four decimal integers separated with dots, checks that it did indeed succeed, and checks whether each number is in [0;255]. That is, it checks whether the string is a valid IPv4 address.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I can't use library functions, so I need to know a way to do something like sscanf but without library functions.